# Need advice or help i have stage menu code that i build using tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, menu, game-development

stagee.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import * 
from chara import CharaSelection
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class GameStage:    
    def __init__(self, chara):
        self.chara = chara
        self.chara.draw_menu()
        self.stage_menu = tk.Tk()
        self.stage_menu.title("Stage Menu")
        self.stage_menu.configure(bg="black")
        self.stage_menu.geometry("700x700")

        bg = Image.open("Gambar/UI_AWAL/bglevel.png")
        bg_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(bg)
        lab = Image.open("Gambar/coba/levelselect.gif")
        lab_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(lab)
        pic = Image.open("Gambar/coba/level1.gif")
        pic_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pic)
        pic2 = Image.open("Gambar/coba/level2.gif")
        pic2_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pic2)
        pic3 = Image.open("Gambar/coba/level3.gif")
        pic3_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pic3)
        pic4 = Image.open("Gambar/coba/level4.gif")
        pic4_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pic4)
        pic5 = Image.open("Gambar/coba/level5.gif")
        pic5_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pic5)
        pic6 = Image.open("Gambar/coba/back.gif")
        pic6_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pic6)

        my_label = tk.Label(self.stage_menu, image=bg_image)
        my_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        frame = tk.Frame(self.stage_menu, bg="black")
        frame.pack(pady=20)

        def stage1_action():
            self.stage_menu.destroy()
            from ClassData import Game
            game = Game()
            game.setup(self.chara.selected_character, self.chara.selected_character2, self.chara.selected_character3,
                    self.chara.selected_character4)
            
        def stage2_action():
            self.stage_menu.destroy()
            from ClassData2 import Game2
            game = Game2()
            game.setup(self.chara.selected_character, self.chara.selected_character2, self.chara.selected_character3,
                    self.chara.selected_character4)

        def stage3_action():
            self.stage_menu.destroy()
            from ClassData3 import Game3
            game = Game3()
            game.setup(self.chara.selected_character, self.chara.selected_character2, self.chara.selected_character3,
                    self.chara.selected_character4)

        def stage4_action():
            self.stage_menu.destroy()
            from ClassData4 import Game4
            game = Game4()
            game.setup(self.chara.selected_character, self.chara.selected_character2, self.chara.selected_character3,
                    self.chara.selected_character4)

        def stage5_action():
            self.stage_menu.destroy()
            from ClassData5 import Game5
            game = Game5()
            game.setup(self.chara.selected_character, self.chara.selected_character2, self.chara.selected_character3, self.chara.selected_character4)


        label = tk.Label(self.stage_menu, image=lab_image, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        label.pack(pady=0)

        stage1_button = tk.Button(self.stage_menu, image=pic_image, command=stage1_action, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        stage1_button.pack(pady=10)

        stage2_button = tk.Button(self.stage_menu, image=pic2_image, command=stage2_action, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        stage2_button.pack(pady=10)

        stage3_button = tk.Button(self.stage_menu, image=pic3_image, command=stage3_action, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        stage3_button.pack(pady=10)

        stage4_button = tk.Button(self.stage_menu, image=pic4_image, command=stage4_action, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        stage4_button.pack(pady=10)

        stage5_button = tk.Button(self.stage_menu, image=pic5_image, command=stage5_action, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        stage5_button.pack(pady=10)

        self.stage_menu.mainloop()
```

gameover.py

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from menustage import GameMenu

class GameOver:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.title("Game Over, your HP is 0")
        self.window.geometry("700x700")
        self.window.configure(bg="black")
        
        self.bg = PhotoImage(file="Gambar/UI_AWAL/bgscreen.png")
        self.pic = PhotoImage(file="Gambar/UI_AWAL/gameover.png")
        self.pic2 = PhotoImage(file="Gambar/UI_AWAL/backk.png")
        
        self.my_label = tk.Label(self.window, image=self.bg)
        self.my_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.window, bg="black")
        self.frame.pack(expand=True, pady=200)
        
        self.label = tk.Label(self.frame, image=self.pic, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.label.pack(pady=0)

        self.start_button = tk.Button(self.frame, image=self.pic2, command=self.kembali, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.start_button.pack(pady=10)

        self.window.mainloop()
        
    def kembali(self):
        self.window.destroy()
        GameMenu()
```

what I need advice is if user already done play with the first stage and after game over he press `kembali` method and sent back to main menu and select character again the first stage button is hide and not shown in the screen on second round he play but when the user exit the game the button is back show to the user.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] that doesn't require us to have a dozen images. Are the images really necessary _for the purposes of this question_ or could you use labels with text?

Comment: Avoid calling `mainloop()` inside `__init__()`.